# Inserting spaces every 3-4 characters

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
1231231234
```

I wish to insert a space every 3 - 4 characters, so it's formatted like so:

123 123 1234

Is this possible with regex? I have something that enters a space every 3 characters but I am unsure how to do a mix of 3 and 4 characters to get the above format.

```
value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
```

Comment: When 3 and when 4?

Comment: It's in the example above.

Comment: So every string is made of the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4? And it's either 123 or 1234?

Comment: Do you always have a 10 characters string without spaces? Just use `slice` or `substring`. Using a regex is pointless here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookahead.

The [Positive Lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) looks for the pattern after the equal sign, but does not include it in the match.

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{3,4}?(?=...)/g, '$& ');
}

console.log(format(1234567890));
console.log(format(123456789));
console.log(format(1234567));
console.log(format(123456));
console.log(format(1234));
console.log(format(123));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
value = "1231231234";

console.log(value.replace(/^(.{3})(.{3})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// add spaces after every 4 digits (make sure there's no trailing whitespace)
somestring.replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/,'')
```